# Why does a simple JS autoclicker break the page?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an autoclicker script that runs while a mouse is held in a left click (e.g. holding down the left click spams clicks), and want it to not just run on a specific element, for example `button-2`, but wherever the mouse is. I came up with this little script:

```js
var mouseDown = 0;
document.onmouseup = function() {
  --mouseDown;
}

function printMousePos(event) {
    ++mouseDown;
    while(mouseDown){
        document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY).click();
    }
}

document.addEventListener("mousedown", printMousePos);


let clicks = 0;

document.body.onclick = function(){ 
  clicks++; 
  document.body.innerText = clicks; 
 }
```

However, as shown when you run the snippet, it appears to break the page (make it unresponsive). Why does this happen?

Thanks!

#### EDIT:

Thanks to @VLAZ's comment, I tried to fix the unescapable `while` loop by using `setInterval`, however, it still doesn't seem to work. Why is this happening?

```js
var mouseDown = 0;
let removeMouse = function() {
    console.log(mouseDown)
  --mouseDown;
}

function click(x,y){
    var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    var el = document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
    ev.initMouseEvent(
        "click",
        true, true,
        window, null,
        x, y, 0, 0,
        false, false, false, false,
        0, null
    );
    el.dispatchEvent(ev);
}

function printMousePos(event) {
    ++mouseDown;
    setInterval(()=> {
        if(mouseDown){
            console.log(mouseDown)
            click(event.clientX, event.clientY);
        } else {
            clearInterval()
        }
    }, 1)
}

document.addEventListener("mousedown", printMousePos);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", removeMouse);

var count = 0;
document.documentElement.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    count++;
    document.body.innerText = count.toString();
})
```

#### EDIT:

I managed to piece together a cool little script based off of @Roko's answer, however, it doesn't seem to work on websites like https://clickspeedtest.com/ or https://www.clickspeedtester.com/, or really any website for that matter. Is their a reason for this? Thanks!

Here's the code:

```js
let intervalHandler = null;

const Mouse = {
  mousedown(ev){
    this.isDown = true;
    this.autoClick(ev)
  },
  mouseup(){ 
    this.isDown = false; 
    clearInterval(intervalHandler)
  },
  mouseover(ev) { 
    if(intervalHandler) clearInterval(intervalHandler)
    if (this.isDown) this.autoClick(ev); 
  },
};
Object.defineProperties(Mouse, {
  isDown: {
    value: false,
    writable: true,
  },
  autoClick: {
    value: (ev) => {
      const ELFP = document.elementFromPoint(ev.clientX, ev.clientY);
      intervalHandler = setInterval(() => {
        ELFP.click();
      }, 100)
    }
  }
});
Object.keys(Mouse).forEach(t => document.addEventListener(t, Mouse[t].bind(Mouse)));

// Demo with buttons
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(EL => 
  EL.addEventListener("click", () => console.log(EL.id))
);
```

```html
<button id="a" type="button">BUTTON 1</button>
<button id="b" type="button">BUTTON 2</button>
```

Comment: `while(mouseDown)` will never finish. Since the loop blocks the thread -> no events would be handled -> nothing will ever change `mouseDown` to break out of the loop.

Comment: PS: Never use `on*` handlers (unless you create a brand new element from in-memory. But even than it's not a wise idea.). You might override already added listeners to that element ad absurdum. Use  `Element.addEventListener("eventName", f)` instead.

Comment: PS: use `textContent` instead of `innerText`. Yes, I know it's similar to `innetHTML`... but don't.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for commenting! Would I use something like `setInterval` then?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks for the comments! If I need to attach the listeners, should I do `document.documentElement.addEventListener`? Also, I will use textContext instead. Thanks :)

Comment: Depends on what you want to do and how. I played around with automating Cookie Clicker some time back and I made a function that will click a number of times in a loop then *stop* in order to let the UI catch up. This would be in a `setInterval` so I'd get clicks in "bursts" and allow the browser to catch up in between. It's probably not completely generic approach but still adaptable to many other clickers.

Comment: @VLAZ That sounds pretty interesting! However, I'm trying to get it to click where the mouse is, not just on a specific element. If this is possible, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: @VLAZ I edited the post, showing what I have tried now. Why doesn't the latest one work? Thanks!

Comment: @divinelemon If I got your question well - added an answer in the hope ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) `Mouse` Object with default browser listeners iterable Methods for
  `"mousedown"` `"mouseup"` `"mouseover"` Events.
- Afterwards assign to your Singleton additional [non-enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) properties:
  `isDown` (Boolean) to handle if the mouse is down or up
  `autoClick` (Function) that will trigger on the `"mouseover"` event.
- Assign your [enumerable keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) ("EventTypes") method in a `forEach` manner to the `Window.document` object

```js
const Mouse = {
  mousedown()   { this.isDown = true; },
  mouseup()     { this.isDown = false; },
  mouseover(ev) { if (this.isDown) this.autoClick(ev); },
};
Object.defineProperties(Mouse, {
  isDown: {
    value: false,
    writable: true,
  },
  autoClick: {
    value: (ev) => {
      const ELFP = document.elementFromPoint(ev.clientX, ev.clientY);
      ELFP.click();
    }
  }
});
Object.keys(Mouse).forEach(t => document.addEventListener(t, Mouse[t].bind(Mouse)));

// DEMO TIME:
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(EL => 
  EL.addEventListener("click", () => console.log(EL.id))
);
```

```html
<button id="a" type="button">BUTTON 1</button>
<button id="b" type="button">BUTTON 2</button>
```

To continuously spam the `"click"` event (as fast as possible) you could do like:

```js
const spamClick = (ev) => {
  const ms = 1; // Repeat every 1 millisecond
  const EL = ev.currentTarget;
  ev.type === "mousedown" ? EL._itv = setInterval(() => EL.click(), ms) : clearInterval(EL._itv) ;
};
["mousedown", "mouseup", "mouseleave"].forEach(evtName => 
  document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(EL =>
    EL.addEventListener(evtName, spamClick)
  )
);

// FOR THIS DEMO ONLY:
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(EL =>
  EL.addEventListener("click", () => console.log(EL.id))
);
```

```html
<button id="a" type="button">BUTTON 1</button>
<button id="b" type="button">BUTTON 2</button>
```

Additional read:

- MDN: [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Thanks for answering! How would I use it? Could you use an example? I would like it to constantly click at the mouse position while the mouse is held down. I can see you get the position of the mouse and click on the element, but how would I call `mouse.autoClick`?

Comment: @divinelemon see the example above: Mousedown on `body` and hold the mousedown - Than move to the buttons and see the console.log yield the elements IDs - same as the default click handler yielding the elements IDs.

Comment: Awesome! However, I wanted it to continuously click the button; For example, when you hold the mouse over the first button you should see "a" being spammed in the console. If you can add that, I will gladly mark this as the answer! Thanks!

Comment: @divinelemon now that I see what you're after - added another much simpler example. Paste the code into those websites Developer console - and have fun. And don't be sad after you realize that the top score will always be higher that you could possibly achieve: `topScoreResult = yourScore + randomFloat` (yep, the score is not stored in any database, it's just a clickbait) ;)

Comment: Thanks again! I will accept this as the answer. Is there any way to make this work for all elements, not just buttons? Thanks!

Comment: @divinelemon have you tried with `document.querySelectorAll("*")` ;)